# How can I send an advertisement from the Genuino and connect to the Galileo via Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, intel, bluetooth-lowenergy, intel-galileo

I'm trying to send data via bluetooth from an Intel *Genuino* to an Intel *Galileo*. The Galileo will act as the Master node in this connection. I have configured the Galileo so that it is discovering bluetooth devices and I have paired my phone to the Galileo via bluetooth.

What I need to do is pair the Genuino with the Galileo. I have tried some of the sample programs that Arduino provides but I cant seem to pair or connect the two devices.

So the question is, if I have my Galileo discoverable and ready to pair, how can I send an advertisement from the Genuino and connect to the Galileo.

*Alternatively:* if anybody has a link to a site that explains the blePeripheral and bleCentral commands, that would be great.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Arduino/Genuino 101 board, use [CurieBle](https://github.com/01org/corelibs-arduino101/tree/master/libraries/CurieBle/src) to create a peripheral. There are some [example sketches](https://github.com/01org/corelibs-arduino101/tree/master/libraries/CurieBle/examples) to get you started. CurieBle works very similar to the [Arduino BLEPeripheral library](https://github.com/sandeepmistry/arduino-BLEPeripheral).

You don't need to pair devices. On the Genuino 101, run the sketch that creates the Bluetooth LE Service. On the Galileo, run a program that discovers service running on the 101 and connects to it. You can write the program for the Galileo using [noble](https://github.com/sandeepmistry/noble) and Node.js.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. I eventually got the two devices connected and exchanging data. I have some more work to do, so the links you have provided should be very helpful. Much appreciated

Comment: You're welcome. Glad you got it working. Can you mark this as the selected answer?

Comment: Sorry I tried to click up vote the other day but it wouldnt let me. I didnt realise I could mark it as selected answer at the time. Thanks again